# TeamCity with MSBuild - Getting the Build folder name?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

The following MSBuild script works, but I have to hard code the work folder (**GetAssemblyIdentity** line) that TeamCity uses.

How do I get "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8ffbe14de0bdf3" **dynamically**?

```
<Target Name="GetVersion">
<GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8ffbe14de0bdf3\AAA.Online.Web\bin\AAA.Online.Web.dll">
  <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="myAssemblyInfo"/>
</GetAssemblyIdentity>
<PropertyGroup>
  <Pattern>(\d+)\.(\d+)</Pattern>
  <In>%(myAssemblyInfo.Version)</In>
  <OutVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</OutVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Could you use a path relative to the MSBuild project file, using $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) property?

Comment: teamcitty.build.working.dir can be injected into the MSBuild build parameters on the command line (something like "/p:AgentWorkFolder=teamcity.build.working.dir" can be used on the MSBuild command line). See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-AgentBuildProperties
Then use ... GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(AgentWorkFolder)\..." in your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in teamcity variables.
Change your code to:

```
<Target Name="GetVersion">
<GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(teamcity_build_checkoutDir)\AAA.Online.Web\bin\AAA.Online.Web.dll">
  <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="myAssemblyInfo"/>
</GetAssemblyIdentity>

<Message Text="Path is $(teamcity_build_checkoutDir)"/>

<PropertyGroup>
  <Pattern>(\d+)\.(\d+)</Pattern>
  <In>%(myAssemblyInfo.Version)</In>
  <OutVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</OutVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```